# how to setup debugging in pycharm with nose on mac

Tags: python-3.x, debugging, pycharm, nose

I have python3 and nosetests successfully setup in a virtual environment in Pycharm able to run `nosetests -s` and see all my tests pass locally. However when I hit the debug button on Pycharm I just get the following output:

```
/Users/appollo_liu/Documents/workspace/WalnutiQ/wAlnut/wAlnut_environment/bin/python "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py" --multiproc --qt-support --client 127.0.0.1 --port 49850 --file /Users/appollo_liu/Documents/workspace/WalnutiQ/wAlnut/model/common_cortical_algorithm_v1.py
pydev debugger: process 11232 is connecting

Connected to pydev debugger (build 162.1967.10)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Question: Is PyCharm debugging suppose to work out of the box? If so how do I set it up with Nosetests or is there another recommended Python3 unit test library?

Link to project I'm trying to debug in PyCharm:

[image]